# Reset the state of a page in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.0

I have a a few iron pages where 'home' is my home page. It has a bunch on game cards in it and when the user clicks on a card, it will start a quiz with a bunch of questions. When I go back to the home page and click on a card again, it doesn't start the quiz. It just continues from the previous state. How can I make it start the quiz again. Below are my pages. I'm using the starter kit from Polymer

```
<iron-pages
  selected="[[page]]"
  attr-for-selected="name"
  fallback-selection="view404"
  selected-attribute="visible"
  role="main"
>
  <my-home name="home"></my-home>
  <my-login name="login"></my-login>
  <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
  <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
  <my-game name="game"></my-game>
</iron-pages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just had this issue: [PolymerElements/iron-pages#53](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-pages/issues/53)

As suggested [in a comment](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-pages/issues/53#issuecomment-306440932), you can check out the [iron-lazy-pages](https://github.com/TimvdLippe/iron-lazy-pages) that has support for `dom-if` and so its `restamp` feature.

UPDATE: example

```
<iron-lazy-pages
  selected="[[page]]"
  attr-for-selected="data-route"
  fallback-selection="view404"
  selected-attribute="visible"
  role="main">
    <template is="dom-if" data-route="home" restamp>
      <my-home></my-home>
    </template>

    ...
</iron-lazy-pages>
```

NOTE: I haven't tested the example, but it's really similar to the [dom-if example on the iron-lazy-pages repo](https://github.com/TimvdLippe/iron-lazy-pages#dom-if-support).

Comment: how does that work for multiple pages. This seems to be for multiple tabs. How can I specify it for my-game page

Comment: Using the `attr-for-selected="data-route"` attribute of the `iron-lazy-pages`, you can wrap your page inside a `dom-if` e add the `restamp` attribute wherever you need.

Comment: do I need to use <template> for this? or is the <my-game> element enough

Comment: I have added an example. You need the `<template>` for calling the `dom-if` correctly and using the `restamp`.

Comment: It worked thanks. But can you tell me how to do it manually. I tried using `_visibleChanged` like below

Comment: _visibleChanged() { new Game() };

Answer (score 1):

iron-lazy-pages v2.2.1 don't work well

I used the "iron-page" like this, it works very well

```js
      isEqual(val1, val2) {
        return val1 == val2;
      }
```

```html
 <iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="data-route" fallback-selection="view404" role="main">
      <!--User block-->
      <div data-route="login">
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isEqual('login',page)}}" restamp>
          <user-login></user-login>
        </template>
      </div>
      <div data-route="view404">
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isEqual('view404',page)}}" restamp>
          <my-view404></my-view404>
        </template>
      </div>
    </iron-pages>
```

it work perfectly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with LINKS. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks